# Android: use a ready Django database?

Tags: java, android, django, database, sqlite

I already have an SQLite database created using Django that I want to use for my android application. The database has four columns, let's say "title", "text", "begin", "end", and I want to take, for example, the 20th row and output the values in some textviews in my app. Most of the tutorials online seem outdated and confusing. Could someone provide some direction, perhaps even a few lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write DatabaseHelper, you can use [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) library for this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper{
     // connection stuff
}
```

Sample application on [github](https://github.com/bfil/android-ormlite-sample)

Comment: Probably a very basic question, but how do I install the library?

Comment: simple add dependecies to gradle.settings file. more information: http://www.horaceheaven.com/android-ormlite-tutorial/

Comment: How should I set up the DB_PATH? My database is in the assets folder, which is located in the same folder as the java and res. Also, your sample application shows how to create a new db item, but how can I use an already existing one? Thank you

Comment: On github U have example project with existing database.

Comment: The getAll function return a List with size 0. Any ideas?